# Defining an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we have to prove that the multiplicative group of integers modulo $8$, $U(8)$, is isomorphic to a set of matrices, are we allowed to define the isomorphism by saying:

$$\begin{align}
[1]&\mapsto (\text{matrix}) \\
[2] &\mapsto (\text{matrix})  \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{align}$$

Or, can we only define the isomorphism by a rule (for example, $f(x) = \pmatrix{x & 0\\0&x}$ is a "rule") that works for each element in $U(8)$?

Comment: I don't know what $U(8)$ is - you might want to explain a bit more. If you're asking whether it's ok to define a function on a finite set by specifying the image of each element individually (rather than 'giving a formula'), then the answer is yes.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify the question based on my understanding of it.  If I've misconstrued the intent of this question, please edit it back.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that by $U_8$ you are referring to the group of units modulo $8$.  (Also denoted $\mathbb{Z}_8^*$, and a whole bunch of other ways.)

It is perfectly acceptable to define a function by enumerating the individual mappings.  For example, I could define a function $f:U_8\to \{1, i, -1, -i\}$ by stating:
$$\begin{align}
f([1]) &= 1\\
f([3]) &= i\\
f([5]) &= -1\\
f([7]) &= -i
\end{align}$$
This defines such a function $f$.  (Note that I'm not checking to see if this particular $f$ is an isomorphism, but it is certainly possible to do so.)